# Is there a T-SQL shortcut for getting the max values of two columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

What I mean is, say you have a table like:

```
Col1 Col2
---- ----
 1    1
 1    9
 2    1
 2    3
 4    1
 4    2
```

I want to get: Col1=4 and Col2=2, because Col1 has precendence. In other words, I want the largest value of Col1 and for that value the largest value of Col2 in a minimal T-SQL expression. It's almost like saying:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Col1, Col2
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY Col1, Col2 DESC
```

But doing this in such a way that the Col1, Col2 values are usable within another query.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean when you say "such a way that the Col1, Col2 values are usable within another query."  Based on what you say up until that point, the query you provided would work if you also ordered Col1 descending.

Answer (score 3):

Not really anything like `MAX(Col1, Col2)`. If you wanted to simulate `MAX ... GROUP BY X` you could use

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY X ORDER BY Col1 DESC, Col2 DESC) AS RN
FROM MyTable
)
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
          X
FROM T
WHERE RN= 1;
```

Comment: Partition with ORDER BY, nice!

Answer (score 2):

Like this? One row

```
SELECT ...
FROM
   SOmeTable
   JOIN
   (
    SELECT TOP 1 Col1, Col2
    FROM MyTable
    ORDER BY Col1, Col2 DESC
    ) foo ON S.Col1 = foo.Col1
```

Or per outer row?

```
SELECT ...
FROM
   SOmeTable S
   CROSS APPLY
   (
    SELECT TOP 1 Col2
    FROM MyTable M
    WHERE S.somecol = M.SomeCol
    ORDER BY Col2 DESC
    ) foo

SELECT ...
FROM
   SOmeTable S
   CROSS APPLY
   (
    SELECT Col1, MAX(Col2) AS MaxCOl2
    FROM MyTable M
    GROUP BY Col1
    ) foo ON S.Col1 = foo.Col1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t(Col1,maxCol1,maxCol2) AS (
  SELECT
    Col1,
    MAX(Col1) OVER(),
    MAX(Col2) OVER(PARTITION BY Col1)
)
SELECT TOP 1 maxCo11,maxCol2 FROM t WHERE Col1 = maxCol1
```